# C++ finding class in vector using std::find raises errors

Tags: c++, class, vector

I'm trying to find a SnekNode object in an std::vector using

```
    auto it = std::find(snek_node_container.begin(), snek_node_container.end(), snek_node);
```

but it raises a compiler error:

> Error C2676   binary '==': 'SnekNode' does not define this operator or a
> conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

which points to the xutility file as source which is not very helpful. When I try to define a == function in the class such as:

```
        SnekNode operator== (const SnekNode& rhs) {
        return (*this == rhs);
    }
```

I get another compilation error:

> C2451 conditional expression of type "SnekNode" is illegal

which also points to the xutility file which again, sadly doesn't help me. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `operator==` should return `bool` or something convertible to `bool`.

Comment: The error literally says what's wrong with your code

Comment: Also, your operator definition creates infinite recursion. You need to actually compare each member on your own (or use C++20 and `=default`)

Comment: A) operator == should return bool typically, B) as youve defined it, that operator is infinitely recursive because it calls itself... how is that supposed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator==` should return bool.

Also, you need to compare the members individually. In your code you just call `operator==` again, causing infinite recursion.

What you can do is use the `operator==` in `operator!=` to save typing, e.g.:

```
struct SnekNode
{
    bool operator== (const SnekNode& rhs) const {
        return a == rhs.a &&
            b == rhs.b && 
            c == rhs.c;
    }

    bool operator!= (const SnekNode& rhs) const {
        return !(*this == rhs);
    }

    // auto operator<=>(const SnekNode&) const = default; // C++20

    int a{0};
    int b{1};
    int c{2};
};
```

With C++20 you can use [default comparisons](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons) (spaceship operator).

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ovrdG8)